# Html+jQuery: фикс меню

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, javascript, php

Сейчас вид такой

[image: img1]

Изображение готового, нарисованного вида

[image: img2]

Что только не пробовал, не могу убрать это место между ними

**сам код**

```
<div>
<a href="javascript://" class="splLink">
<span class="clickable small" onclick="user_stats({postrow.POST_ID}, {postrow.POSTER_ID})"><img src="./templates/default/images/tor_stat.png"></span>
</a>
<div>
<span id="user_stats_{postrow.POST_ID}" style="display:none"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><td class="row1"><b>Загрузка...</b></td></table></span>
</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
    .test {
  line-height:0.9;
  border="0";
  hspace="0";
  vspace="0"; 
  background: url('http://data1.floomby.com/files/share/24_12_2012/voFSGoFu0GVmKprS1Ju1g.png') 100%, 100%, no-repeat;
  background-size:auto;
  height: 66px;
  width: 145px;
}

.dl_bg { 
background: url("../images/dl_bg_cellpic.jpg") repeat-x #CFCFCF;
}

.splCont{
    display:none;border:1px solid #cccccc;padding:3px 5px;
}
```

**ajax.php**

```
    function user_stats()
    {
    global $bb_cfg, $lang;
    $user_id = (int) $this->request['user_id'];
    $btu = get_bt_userdata($user_id);

    $ratio = get_bt_ratio($btu);
    $u_up_total = humn_size($btu['u_up_total']);
    $u_up_bonus = humn_size($btu['u_up_bonus']);
    $u_up_release = humn_size($btu['u_up_release']);
    $u_down_total = humn_size($btu['u_down_total']);
    if ($btu['u_down_total'] < MIN_DL_FOR_RATIO) $ratio = '---';
    ############ Закончили ###################
    ############ Выводим данные ##############
    $this->response['post_id'] = (int) $this->request['post_id'];
    $this->response['html'] = '
        <div class="test">
        <div class="table-wrap">
        <p align="left" class="from">&nbsp&nbsp<em>'.$lang['BT_RATIO'].':</em> '.$ratio.'</p>
        <p align="left" class="from">&nbsp&nbsp<em>'.$lang['DOWNLOADED'].':</em> '.$u_down_total.'</p>
        <p align="left" class="from">&nbsp&nbsp<em>'.$lang['UPLOADED'].':</em> '.$u_up_total.'</p>
        </div>
        </div>
';
}
```

Comment: А почему в css присутствует знак "="? Уберите этот кусок вообще:
  border="0";
  hspace="0";
  vspace="0";

Answer (score 1):

Я бы на вашем месте воспользовался firebugом, например. У него есть полезная функция inspect element, там можно узнать откуда ноги (css наследие) растут ;)

я вот посмотрел и нашел в чем проблема... ( возможно ;) )

```
<div style="line-height:0px;">
 <a class="splLink" href="javascript://">
  <span class="clickable small" onclick="user_stats(3, 2)">
    <img none;="" 0px="" border:="" src="./templates/default/images/torrent_stats.png">
   </span>
 </a>
  <div class="splCont" style="border-top: 0px;">
   <span id="user_stats_3" style="">
     <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     </table>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

посмотрите на первый `DIV` и `DIV` с классом `splCount`
`line-height` уберет зазор между ними... и все это было прямо налету выяснено через FireBug.........

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: а в новой версии firefox разве доступен firebug?